# How to position a button to be always a certain distance from the screen in css?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I want my doButton to be 30px from the right edge of the screen and my Fund button to be 30px from the left edge of the screen like:

```
 FundButton      Item task descriptiion goes here                   DoButton
```

Here is my HTML

```
      <div ng-repeat="x in todoList">
      <li class="item item-checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox">
      </label>
      <!-- this is the checkbox element, you will see it is bound to the done setting in the items array -->
      <!-- When clicked it calls the update function to update the item to its done status -->
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.done" ng-click="update()"></input>
      <!-- this is a span tag that shows the item text, I am using ng-bind, instead of the span tag we could have used {{x.todoText}} as well -->
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<span><button class="fund-button">Fund</button>       </span>
    <span>{{x.todoText}} </span> <span>      <button class="doButton">Do</button></span>
      </li>
      </div>
```

My css so far:

My css

```
.doButton{
float: left;
clear: left ;
}

.fund-button{
clear: right;
float: right

}
```

Comment: where is your css? for this you just need to float the `FundButton` left and the `DoButton` right.

Comment: get rid of all the inline css, fix the formatting/indentation to make it readable, and put proper classes/id's on things to start.

Comment: I just included my css

Comment: why are you wrapping your buttons in `<span>`'s? You are essentially floating your buttons to the left and right of the spans. The spans however are displaying in their normal inline way. Get rid of the spans and you should be all set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the wrapping `<span>`'s from your buttons. They are preventing your floats from displaying the way you expect.

Also, you don't need the `clear: left;` and `clear: right;` in your css

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwwcov77/2/)

Answer (score 0):

By adding margin-left to the tags, you can shift the divs over by the corresponding amount of space.

```
.doButton{
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left ;
    margin-left:30px;
}
.fund-button{
    display:inline-block;
    clear: right;
    float: right
    margin-right:30px;
}
```